# Can you give me some suggestions on my problem?

Tags: c

I want to solve the problem. The problem is to check whether the number is palindrome or not.
There has been a lot of solutions that exist online. But I am trying to solve this problem through my approach without seeing any solution from the internet. I am trying this way->

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
//Declaring variables for further proceed
int number,reminder,quotient=1;

//Just take the input from the user
printf("Input : ");
scanf("%d",&number);

while(quotient!=0){
    quotient=number/10;
    reminder=number%10;
    printf("%d",reminder);
    number=quotient;

  }



   return 0;
 }
```

The problem is : My code is work for displaying the reverse order of any given number. But I could not check with this reverse order with the given number. If you can then you are most welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's ok sir. @kiranBiradar

Comment: Please change your question title.

Comment: Can you give me some suggestions about my title?. Then It will be easy to update my question.@kiranBiradar

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I challenge your duplicate, though you are of course aware that I know the close relation of the two questions. I accept the two to be two different questions from different angles (at least from point of view of the asker) on the same problem. This one is "my code is close, how can I extend/change it" the other one is a nicely abstract decent request for an approach. Yes, combining both probably answers both. But you need to know the solution to see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applaud your decision to follow your approach through.
Allow me to start a step-by-step answer according to the compromise described here (applicable to homework, challenges and very disciplined self-learners like you):
[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Step 1:
You program is able to look at digit by digit of the number in the right order (you can output them). But it does not get an overview of them. You do not store them. Neither separatly nor as a whole (string or number). Consider how to change that.
Do you know a way to store several seperate digits?
Do you know a way to store a string of characters?

Aleternatively, if you do not want to store the reordered digits, i.e. if you want to continue looking at single digits, then you need to always look at two single digits, one pair after the other. Each pair needs to consist of one digit from the high end and one digit from the low end. Maybe you can think of a way to start the number from both ends while looping. More variables to store intermediate results might help with this.

Step 2:
You "know a little bit of the way how to store a string of characters", so do that. Store the characters which you output. If you do not know how to get from digit to character read up on `sprintf()`. This is a little complex, because the goal is to have a single string, not several strings with one digit each. So ...

Alternatively, to store single digits as their own integers, read up on "arrays". You specifically need an array of `int`.

If both seems to complicated do not forget the alternative from first step, to look at pairs of digits, from both ends of the number. For that try to print for example for the input "654321" the output "6:1, 5:2, 4:3". If you can do that, things get much easier.

Comment: Sir, First of all, Thank you for your support. I do not know how to store several separate digits. But I know a little bit of the way how to store a string of characters @Yunnosch

Comment: Ok sir, I am trying.

Comment: Take your time. I intend to feedback on any progress or failure you report. Though it may take some time to respond.

Comment: Ok, sir. Sir, can I connect with you on the other platform? like Facebook, LinkedIn. If I can follow you then I can learn a lot from you.@Yunnosch.

Comment: Sorry. I personally do not use those platforms, and from point of view of StackOverflow code of conduct it would be inappropriate to make the contact, even if I did.

Comment: Ok sir, Is there any privilege that exists in stack overflow that I can follow you.

Comment: I appreciate the praise, though I am not sure what you mean by "follow". You can see my profile and read the stuff I spout (I also do stupid things you know....). Please do NOT get the idea to upvote many of my posts. That would shed a doubtful light on both of us.

Comment: Ok sir, From now I will try to maintain the guideline which is provided from the StackOverflow when I will make a reply on other's answers as a comment.

Comment: Just to be clear, I do not think that you broke any rule. (Yet. That I am aware of. In posts/comments I am aware of....) Actually I kind of like your style. If you say "only approach" (like oh so many others do) you do not complain if you really only get an approach (and oh so many others do that in that situation...).

Comment: In case you are serious about wanting to strictly play by the rules there is a lot to be read starting here: [tour] (which is also something of a good luck charme, because experienced users here can tell if you have completely read that or not...).

Comment: Ok, sir, I will try my best to follow all of the rules from now.

Comment: Have fun. Help others. ;-)

Comment: Ok, sir, I will be very gladful If I can assist others and wish a good day for you. Keep up the good work.

Comment: Sir, I posted my solution to the answer section above. Please give a review of my solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Write a program to check the number whether it is palindrome or not

#include <stdio.h>
int
main(void){

//Put variables for the further proceed
int number, quotient=1, remainder,i=0;

//To declare a character array
char text[100];

//To show the message to the user
printf("Enter an integer number :");

//Taking input from the user
scanf("%d",&number);

//For finding escape the integer number in the reverse order specifically
int number_update=number;

//To find out the integer number in the reverse order
  while(quotient!=0){
  quotient=number_update/10;
  remainder=number_update%10;
  number_update=quotient;
  text[i] = remainder + '0';//Converts integer to character and store to the array
  i++;
  }
 //Converts the string to a whole integer
  int result_of_reverse=atoi(text);

  //Check the result of reverse order with the given integer number
  if(result_of_reverse==number){

    //To display the result
    printf("This is a palindrome number");
  }
  else{

    //To display the result
    printf("This is not a palindrome number");
  }

}
```

Eventually, I have solve my problem. Thank you all for your suggestions.