# How to convert a list of multiple integers into a single integer in c?

Tags: c

I have a for loop which runs for 5th time and each time it assigns value to the remainder variable like

remainder=5 when it is the first iteration

remainder=4 when it is the second iteration

remainder=3 when it is the third iteration

remainder=2 when it is the fourth iteration

remainder=1 when it is the fifth iteration

Now, I want to take those into one variable called a number and It will be like number=54321 as a full integer. Is it possible to do it in c?. If possible then please give me the approach. If it is not then how can I do that by using other approaches please explain?. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show what you have tried, and what problems you have encountered.

Comment: To create an integer from digits a, b, c, d, e, you just need to `int var = 10000*a + 1000*b + 100*c + 10*d +e;` Or to generalize: a sum of `10^i * d_i` over `i in {0,n}`

Comment: I see that this is related but not identical to this other of your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63844319/can-you-give-me-some-suggestions-on-my-problem/63844485?noredirect=1#comment112898334_63844485  Looks like you are going at your problem from different angles. Good idea.

Comment: Sir, I am trying to find out the reverse order of an integer then trying to do some bunch of things. I can reverse an integer by splitting it's each digit through quotient and reminder. But I could not store multiple single digits into one integer variable. Hope you understand. @NellieDanielyan

Comment: Thank you sir for your support. @Yunnosch

Comment: Sir, Look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63844319/can-you-give-me-some-suggestions-on-my-problem/63844485?noredirect=1#comment112898334_63844485.I am trying to solve this.@NellieDanielyan

Comment: Ok sir, I am going to try. @pptaszni. Thank you sir.

Comment: That sounds like basic school maths to me.

Comment: What happens when you run out of digits?  You can only get at most 9 to 10 digits.  10, only if the first is 1 or 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All numbers no matter base can be formed by

*digit * base^n + ... + digit * base^1 + digit * base^0*

(This is also the key to understanding binary and hex.)
So for base 10 aka decimal, we can form a number by calculating:

```
5*10^4 + 4*10^3 + 3*10^2 + 2*10^1 + 1*10^0 = 54321
```

You figure out the C code from there, it is fairly trivial but please note that `^` is *not* the "power of" operator in C (but bitwise XOR). So we'd have to calculate it by d`10*10` etc or alternatively call the `pow()` function (which unfortunately uses floating point numbers).

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate that you are not asking for code or for full solution.
So here is the approach you ask for:

- start with 0
- add the value from first iteration
- multiply by 10
- add the value from second iteration
- multiply by 10
- add ...
- ....

You see the pattern, I assume.

Answer (score -1):

You can try function `atoi()`.
[**C library function - atoi()**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm):

> The C library function int atoi(const char *str) converts the string argument str to an integer (type int).

**CODE:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char remainder[4 + 1]; // + 1 for the null terminator
    memset(remainder, 0, sizeof(remainder));

    remainder[strlen(remainder)] = '1';
    remainder[strlen(remainder)] = '2';
    remainder[strlen(remainder)] = '3';
    remainder[strlen(remainder)] = '4';

    printf("remainder=%d\n", atoi(remainder));

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
remainder=1234
```

Comment: I would not trust that without initialising reminder. And the size of the array seems weird, too big and in a some way also to small.

Comment: `4 * sizeof(int)`?? it either works or it doesn't. How about just using `4 + 1`, instead of any multiplication, 1 for the *null terminator*

Comment: No. `sizeof(int)` does not go into this at all.

Comment: the word you're after would be *remAinder*, but no, the whole number will not be the remainder, the 1, 2, 3, 4 etc would be remainders.

Comment: The blame for "reminder" is not on this OP, it is on the OP of the question. See the other question I linked.... @AnttiHaapala

Comment: And `loop-times` (even assuming you mean something like `loop_times`) is also wrong. Off-by-one.

Comment: @Yunnosch even then, OP calls the remainders rem(a)inders, not the entire number :P

Comment: How about vastly improving readability & performance with `for(size_t i=0; i<4; i++) reminder[i] = '1' + i;`

Comment: Being a non-native speaker myself, I try to be forgiving about choice of similar sounding words and little vocabulary mistakes. I get much more annoyed by "wanna, u r a pal, plz" and things like that. @AnttiHaapala

Comment: Haha guys, the OP says **remainder**, I read it wrong to **reminder**. It's my fault. Thanks everybody for correction.

Comment: Spelling is not important, not writing obscure and needlessly slow code is. And now your edit removed the space for null termination for some reason, so nothing will work now.